# Dropdown reset its selected text

Tags: asp.net

[drop down item test1234 and test12345 has same value ABC and ABC. but when I select Test12345 in dropdown, dropdown reset it to test1234](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmWX9.png)

Comment: Please update the question with your code.

Comment: drop down list in asp.net. I have assign datasource to dropdownlist with DataTextField and DataValueField. its working fine if all the values of DataValueField are diffrent if it is same like Test1234 -  ABC, Test12345 - ABC . Now if I select Test12345 from drop dlown, dropdown set text as Test1234 only. Test12345 is ID(DataTextField) and ABC is Name(DataValueField)

Answer (score 0):

You cant have same values in a select(drop-down) option that is he reason best example is Phone number imagine you want to call your friend but there is another person with the same phone number now how would you place a call?

Its ok(not recommended) to have options with same text but not same value